# CSS - first-child selector not working

Tags: css

I am using bulma as css framework, and have a section on my page where I am looping over items, and creating multiline columns.

```
<section class="section employees">
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="(value, key) of employeesGroupedByDepartments">
           <div class="columns is-multiline department">
                <div class="title-with-line">
                  <h4><span>{{ key }}</span></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="employee column is-3" v-for="employee of value">
                    <div class="card">
                        <figure class="image is-96x96">
                            <img :src="employee.image.data.path" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <h4 class="title is-5">
                            {{employee.title}}
                        </h4>
                        <h6 class="subtitle is-6">
                            <small>
                               {{getExtras(employee, 'position')}}
                            </small>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I would like to remove left padding for each first child column, I have tried with setting even to both classes `padding left 0` as important but nothing worked:

```
.employees {

     .column:first-child, employee:first-child {
          padding-left: 0!important;
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you miss "." dot for employee class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.column` is not the first child as you have a div with class `title-with-line` proceeding it. What you're looking for is:

```
.employees {
   .column:nth-child(2), .employee:nth-child(2) {
      padding-left: 0!important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A `.column` will never be a `first-child`, because there is always a `div.title-with-line` before it.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child):

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.

You would need the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector.

Comment: Right, you will have to wrap the divs .column in a new layer